# how to use getSupportFragmentManager() in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I change

```
public class Bmr extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

to

```
public class Bmr extends appcompatactivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

this `getSupportFragmentManager()` is working  but I need to work with `Activity` class. Are there any options how to do it?

Comment: No. You can not. And why do you want to Activity instead appcompatactivity? Activity is parent of appcompatactivity, so you will get all methods of actvity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **can't**. `getSupportFragmentManager()` is only available in [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) and classes that extend it.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html), you can see that **AppCompatActivity** is a **Activity**, so everything in `Activity` is also available in `AppCompatActivity`.

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
                   ↳    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
                       ↳    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all as stated above you need to use AppcompatActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.mainframe,tab1Fragment);
            ft.commit();
         }
}
```

here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainframe"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```