# Can't use getFragmentManager()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment and I want  to add  its data to  another fragment via `getFragmentManager()` but this metod has been deprecated and  now I don't know what to do.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVXIP.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'add its data to another fragment'? A Fragment is a piece of UI. Are you saying you want to add a Fragment to another Fragment's layout?

Comment: Yes sir, that is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().
Visit [Since the Android getFragmentManager() API is deprecated, is there any alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737667/since-the-android-getfragmentmanager-api-is-deprecated-is-there-any-alternati)
for more details .

Comment: how  must I use this  metod?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895333/how-to-use-getsupportfragmentmanager-in-activity/38895391

Comment: Thank you very much, sir, for helping me so much

Comment: Happy to help!!..Please Up-vote the answer so that others can also find it.